# How to display download button in Video in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, html5-video

I am running a Django project and using video.html file for displaying video.

I have below code which is displaying video, but i want to change the play button of video and also introduce a download button like this [image]

```
     <div class="row portfolio-container">
          {% for portfolio in portfolio %}

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item">
<a href="{{ portfolio.file.url }}" download>
              <video id="{{portfolio.id}}"  onclick="videoviews({{portfolio.id}})" class="video-js vjs-theme-forest"  controls preload="auto" width="360" height="264" data-setup="{}">

              <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>

              <source src="{{ portfolio.file.url }}" type="video/mp4" >


              </video>
             </a>
              <div class="mx-auto my-1 col-lg-12 d-block" style="font-size: 10px;">
                <p class="float-left">
                  <span class="font-weight-bold">Uploaded by:</span> <a href="{% url 'profile' username=portfolio.user.username %}">{{portfolio.user}}</a>
                </p>

                 <p class="float-right">
                  <span class="font-weight-bold" id="views{{portfolio.id}}">{{portfolio.views}}</span>
                </p>
              </div>
          </div>
```

I have attached screenshot of current video frame.
[image]
I am a beginner in Django and Javascript, Please help.

Answer (score 0):

add an anchor tag like...

```
<a href="{{ portfolio.file.url }}" download>Download</a>
```

you could try putting the video tag between the anchor tags like...

```
<a href="{{ portfolio.file.url }}" download><video>.....</video></a>
```

know that the use of the video tag is to have and play video files in html documents but if you don't want users to be able to play the video at all, ditch the video tag.

Comment: I am getting download button after opening the video in new window , but it is not shown at the video frame itself. Updated the   video section of code in the question .  It has a loop to show multiple videos in a page itself, where all videos should have download button without opening in new window.

Comment: Include the <a href="{{ portfolio.file.url }}" download>Download</a> Tag in the loop